# Which is faster in SQL server - LIKE in loop or IN Query - Using EF Migration

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-like, in-operator

I need to update a column of a set of rows in a Table with given name.

Which query executes faster:

Update ....
set...
where name in('abc','pqr','mnp','xyz')

or

foreach(string str in namelist){
    Update ....
    set...
    where name like str
}

Comment: Set based operations are usually much, much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a LIKE when you want to use wildcards... otherwise stay away from them as they are very costly. As for loops, I also try to stay away from them as they are usually costly. So My Personal Opinion? One update statement with the IN clause will give you better performance than a loop and a Like.